# merge strings lying between two specific values

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to merge all the strings present in the list into single string, if they lie between 'zz' using python

```
old_list = ['1', 'zz', '1', '2', 'zz', '1', '1', '1', 'zz', '1', 'zz']
```

Expected output:

```
new_list = ['1', '11', '111', '1']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby


old_list = ["1", "zz", "1", "1", "zz", "1", "1", "1", "zz", "1", "zz"]

new_list = []
for k, g in groupby(old_list, lambda k: k == "zz"):
    if not k:
        new_list.append("".join(g))

print(new_list)
```

Prints:

```
['1', '11', '111', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here without external libary

```py
def filter_list(input_list):
    out = []
    zz_index = 1
    if input_list[0] != 'zz':
        zz_index += 1
    cur_item = ""
    for i in input_list:
        if i == 'zz':
            zz_index += 1
            out.append(cur_item)
            cur_item = ""
            zz_index = 0
        else:
            cur_item += i
    return out
```